# PHP video manipulation?

Tags: php, video

I was wondering if there's a server-side script based solution for manipulating audio/video files? By manipulate, i mean encode/decode and slice video into multiple clips and encode/decode them etc..?

I've looked at [FFMPEG project](http://ffmpeg.org/index.html) but am wondering what other solutions there might be...

Comment: ffpeg is very powerful, you might be interested in a wrapper for it. Check this one: http://code.google.com/p/phpvideotoolkit/

Comment: This is not something php can do directly very well. But there are a number of command line tools that can do it for you which you can call with php. (FFMPEG being one of the most common)

Comment: yeah look for ffmpg and SoX for audio (I think that was its name xD)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of video manipulation through PHP, there is no way to do it directly through PHP, All solutions revolve around using exec to call an external library program for editing.

### Calling FFMPEG from PHP

A good example of this approach can be found here:

- http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Video-Conversion-With-FFMPEG.html

Below is an example of execution ffmpeg from php:

```
<?php
    exec("ffmpeg -i video.mpg -an -r 10 -y -s 320x240 video%d.jpg");
?>
```

Additionally, also have a look at the following library: http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

### Calling VLC from PHP

Quoting from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player:

> VLC media player supports many audio and video compression methods and
>   file formats, including DVD-Video, video CD and streaming protocols.
>   It is able to stream over computer network and to transcode multimedia
>   files.

VLC can also be called via command line of the exec method to perform transcoding, streaming, and basic video editing functions such as rotation and cropping.

### Calling Mencoder

Yet again, another option is to use the Mencoder tool that is "a free command line video decoding, encoding and filtering tool released under the GNU General Public License." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEncoder .

Example:

```
<?PHP

 echo "ENCODING\n";

 exec ("start mencoder \"mf://../../*.jpg\" -ofps 25 -o ../test.flv -of lavf -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=flv:keyint=50:vbitrate=600:mbd=2:mv0:trell:v4mv:cbp:last_pred=3  -vop scale=320:240 -lavfopts video");

 echo "\nDONE";

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use virtualdub, anyway, to do it in PHP you need to use exec() function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for getting stuck in with an answer. You might like to give a simple code snipped example of how to do what you're talking about - it really helps the questioner learn from your answer.